# data model creation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-modeling, star-schema

Can we create the data model from the existing database in SQL Server like star schema or snowflake schema pictorial form?
If yes, could you please help me the steps to create the datamodelling in SQL Server.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to object explorer in the SQL Server Management Studio and expand database node. You can right click and generate database diagram, as given below.

[image]